# How can I use Firestore db for multilingual applications?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an iOS application and I need to translate the contents of the databse into multilingual, as I say in the application I'm using Firestore. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Looks like my answer was unaccepted 3 years later. Not sure why as the process described is how we've handle multi-lingual processes for years. For future readers - take a look at my answer and let me know if you need additional clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the text you need in nodes with the variations for the different languages. When the user signs up have them identify what language they prefer and from then on read the text in their language and present it in the UI. Conceptually, it would look like this:

```
go_instructions
   en: "Click the GO button to continue"
   fr: "Cliquez sur le bouton GO pour continuer"
   es: "Haga clic en el botón IR para continuar"
email_instructions
   en: "Enter your email address"
   fr: "Entrez votre adresse email"
   es: "Ingrese su dirección de correo electrónico"
```

Obviously with Firestore you'll set these up as documents with the fields and values beneath but it should get you going the right direction.